# Logic to do Backordering system

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, logic

Greeting all,

I'm currently coming up against a logic problem that I've yet to figure out after two days due that I keep second guessing myself.  Here is the gist of what I'm doing.

I have a orders that come into a site.  Logically, it has already determined how many of a particular item to send on an order based on what is in stock.  If the stock is high enough, it issues that many items requested.

However, there is a twist.  The admins can adjust these order numbers.  They can change the amount requested along with the amount issued.  One rule is that they cannot issue more than requested (issued <= requested in other words).  Here is an example of an order.

A request comes in for a quantity of 5 items.  The number in stock at the time of the order was 4.  The system takes what is in stock and issues it for the order and places a backorder for the remaining item.

Qty = 5
Stock = 4

5 - 4 = 1

Issue Qty = 4

Backorder = 1

There are 4 scenerios that I've come up with to account for all the possible changes.

1.) Admin changes Qty from 5 to 4.  The admin leaves the amount issued alone due that the stock is still 4 and cannot go any higher.  This causes the backorder to need removed.

2.) Admin changes the Qty from 5 to 6, leaves the issued amount alone (in turn due that the stock is empty).  This causes the backorder to need updated to 2.

3.) Admin doesn't change the Qty (5).  The admin changes the issued amount from 4 to 3.  This adds one item back into stock (1).  This causes the backorder to remain 2.

4.) Admin changes both Qty and issued amount to 4.  This leaves the stock at 0.  The backorder is also removed due that it goes down to 0.

My problem is creating logic in code to handle this.  I started by checking the quantity to see if it exceeded the original quantity's.  If it did, I checked the issued amount to see if it was greater than the original amount issued.  And then I keep getting lost.

I'm hoping maybe someone has some ideas.  I really appreciate any help in figuring out this logic.  Thanks.

Comment: You posted case 3 seems to be off. Do you mean the following for it:  
3) Admin doesn't change the Qty (5). The admin changes the issued amount from 4 to 3. This adds one item to stock (1), and the backorder remains 1.

Comment: Fixed.  Thanks for catching that.  Actually, Backorder would go up to 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is already a system for fulfilling the orders (calculates issued & back order numbers), then one way to handle this would be to reverse the operation, apply the admin's changes and re-fulfill the order with the changes.

You'd have to add a field or two to the order to account for the admin's changes, and update the order fulfillment system to account for the specified issued amount.

In this way, you wouldn't need complicated logic for altering what is issued, backordered, etc.

Comment: That semi-makes sense but that would mean I need to update the Stock Quantity, delete the record, then recreate the same record, and add it to the order.  I guess in a round about way it works but I'd much rather not delete records vs. doing the logic.

Comment: Maybe, but I think I prefer to think of the fulfillment record as immutable and what you're really doing is cancelling one fulfillment and substituting one customized by the admin. I also like keeping the fulfillment logic in one place (including admin changes) instead of having a second system doing complex DB updates. Just my opinion